# The state of a coroutine after final-suspend

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

A coroutine has an initial suspend point and a final suspend point. A `coroutine_handle` is [`done`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle/done) when it is suspended at the final suspend point. However, this suspension is done via a `co_await promise.final_suspend()`. And this function can return `std::never_suspend` or a similar awaitable.

So... what happens then? `coroutine_handle::resume` yields UB if the coroutine is suspended at the final suspend point, but what happens if you're *past* the final suspend point?

Presumably, the coroutine is not considered suspended, so [`resume` is UB by that rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle/resume). But what can you do with a handle to a coroutine that is past the final suspend point?

Or is there never any point to having your `final_suspend` return anything other than `std::suspend_always`?

Comment: The coroutine is destroyed if `final_suspend` does not suspend. ["The coroutine state is destroyed when control flows off the end of the coroutine"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#11)

Comment: Raymond also has an excellent blog post about this topic: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210331-00/?p=105028 Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/qGExbP875

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coroutine functions are defined by transformations on what the body of the corotuine is. After the main body of the coroutine finishes and exits (either via `co_return` or running off the end of the block), the following code happens:

```
co_await p.final_suspend();
//destruct promise p
//destruct parameters in coroutine frame
//destroy coroutine state
```

Where `p` is the promise object for the coroutine. So if `final_suspend` doesn't cause a suspension with `co_await`, the promise is destroyed, followed by the parameters of the coroutine frame, followed by the coroutine state object itself.

`coroutine_handle` references a coroutine state. If that has been destroyed, then the handle does not refer to a suspended coroutine (since there is *no* coroutine). And `resume` therefore will have undefined behavior. `done` similarly has UB if the handle is not suspended (because it isn't a handle).