# How to propagate C++ coroutine exceptions back to the caller?

Tags: c++, exception, c++20, c++-coroutine

I want the caller who issues the start/continuation of the coroutine to receive all exceptions thrown in the coroutine body right upon invocation of the coroutine. Is this even possible? Here's what I have:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAHFykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn4JdpgO6bX1BIVhkdF6CnUNTdmtwz3BfSUDXACUtqhexMjsHOYAzMHI3lgA1CYbbk5DxJish9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHmKqridWX13dmWww7Xn2hzcaGIS0cIS%2Bt3u/0ezzcp2CwAA%2BgA3PCYADuULut1OXgcewAsgBPDxgrwQzCHKzQvEEYgEgh7RJglh4JTIggkxJPEwAdlpNz2Ir2Q3QIBAr3e1WRH2Ie2lmA%2B6WRNO%2BorFBAlIERRjRGMxWuIyKoxCYKPVdOFoqYlNQe2AmAIyLOBGWDGRqAi2naBAgcz2AFpLsSySRwVMrbibSLxZKFF4FLyGOhkSFUdE9sE0mJkYnk64A3sGKglR8DoK9m6PZWrPyACI0ytN26a%2BO6pMptNiTFMEkKPY0Zi0fNdouB0vl5kCizV5212cCpsbOfL74a0Wo1B4dDz93ET3b3fFpeNjdtrc7vdeBgIQzoehp6fpU%2BCzeakUvgTI54NrU6sgyxnIIyLfgwAbRpq67Wuuq4Xjc%2BKEqS5KRiEdYfnsSZIiybIcpgXI8nyGz/pKrKoOynLcry0aYR2oJoQR96pvQwLkZRBHUdSGzYHsDGUlG8HWpqKERgJIQQPRYlUsizGPtxbjsfhhE0TxexyfQgYgHx0lTBAGmYIGZ6trGewAH6iRSVJvkKn6ingVB7BA/FUnMmF2SKLlTAAdFgpyoCSkFCaZMExpqx57mciZsJJ2oJgySIGlixqmuawBGe%2Bl52Q5TlgGAXkhL5AiYAGGW2R5moFZg3lKUoAbeacqUWr%2Bhz/o1ZoWlBFWilV3lRT4JVucF3X2Y5zm6YVtWDd54HIm5WUjaKHZuggYKYmBbzKtU41WT5U31bNQ3lXZoXQee0LnsF3x2kQuEUcpXGSk6Lo1oeXo%2Bn6xYhmplmMRhC2vQwdYAZKVWyQ%2BrFHFNKncdgkpmhRcp4XVABUBAIByGUrkKoXfEhzJMH2hBMBE9D/aZUm7SE4MsQp0NcaGBlqsNtr2nshNMIQrrnOggWBt9vERKgnjA4DQ5iEozanazt0c1zBbdrFgETUxEN08jnFEYz/OhhFwNM3%2B6lS%2Bdpk3Q6csvZg0WDcGoYdnqKLosls77rWTM1Rr9XtWlzNribcE47cv3iU8LDhlTmAAGK3h0AhK/FxCJU7Rph6cZV0XFKDgvCwIHGYZioSHWrdJge6YoQCB7KnDKG%2BYZg50cVcDjXwK5x2ri0LRC0APTd3sDY7kYYoUU8mIkAA1ns5fo03pzed5CGatXCqtTpyIW%2BzRN1KT1Lvpdx0g1nlIN24ecFyrOmCMEXil1PFezy3JFnyfD8r0cbeZx3Xemb3/eD8Aw82BVxIKPCed8Z7L3novUU6M1qH0ZFfNgYFiBgmIBAOu2BNoqgEHsWBqBMRA2CLghATxep1yOhnZWx9W6NzroXKkOkWCJHoAQUuC984v3bixLqnlUDcwPAwWi/tbjBGZCwTmEF04LWDgwqqhsw70KmNHf42064AAlKi0FQOQnhuDiAknJhVXq/UYp1wAOokFoOgHRLMRTLj4kwAgyBK7jQYEMQ%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%2BpTZ0CYCb%2BgxGTRMKNMahjdHzTMQtrqlgrBlTU%2BpsyUULL2KoWIXigxeMkI6ZAyA9gXO8lwJyuBCAkD6fMXgayRmkDGRMqZHAZmkB5XUyQ3lJAAE5%2BRro0Ju9dm7t1rtIE0lpCylkrMGXMjZ2z9IgHBIkSkhzxonOiKEVgaxW3ts7d23t/aBmlxHYnCUCQJXCFEOIWVwGFVqF%2BSq0gmJzSJF5XOhph7fkLIeZSO9zJUCOXfR2rtwAe19o2AOpyHgn0r1%2BOO89wy5gLBIUwLAMQAxzoXTyyQdTvITKtWuq1XGNA8YSEe%2BZnBT2rIvaM8ZkzakcA2I249InqPrPrRwMwcnhOLMU1Oh1qRnCSCAA%3D)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <coroutine>
#include <string_view>

struct MyCoroutine;

struct promise_type {
    std::exception_ptr exception_;
    std::string_view str_frag_;

    auto get_return_object() -> MyCoroutine;

    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }

    void return_void() {}

    void unhandled_exception() {
        exception_ = std::current_exception();
    }

};

struct MyCoroutine {
    using promise_type = ::promise_type;

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> coroutine;

    MyCoroutine(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle) : coroutine(handle) {}
    ~MyCoroutine() {
        if (coroutine)
            coroutine.destroy();
    }

    void resume(std::string_view str_frag) {
        if (!coroutine.done()) {
            coroutine.promise().str_frag_ = str_frag;
            coroutine.resume();
            if (coroutine.promise().exception_)
                std::rethrow_exception(coroutine.promise().exception_);
        }
    }
};

auto promise_type::get_return_object() -> MyCoroutine {
    return { std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this) };
}

struct awaitable {
    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle_;
    auto await_ready() -> bool { return false; }
    auto await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h) -> void { handle_ = h; }
    auto await_resume() -> std::string_view { return handle_.promise().str_frag_; }
};

MyCoroutine myCoroutineFunction(std::string_view mystr) {
    std::cout << "Coroutine started with mystr = " << mystr << std::endl;

    // Doing some work with mystr..

    mystr = co_await awaitable{};
    std::cout << "Coroutine continued with mystr = " << mystr << std::endl;

    // Doing some more work with mystr..

    throw std::runtime_error("Exception thrown in the coroutine.");
    std::cout << "Coroutine completed." << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

int main() {
    MyCoroutine coroutine = myCoroutineFunction("Hello");
    try {
        coroutine.resume("World");
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception in the caller context: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This yields

```
Coroutine started with mystr = Hello
Coroutine continued with mystr = World
Caught exception in the caller context: Exception thrown in the coroutine.
```

**Problem**: As you can see from above code, I'm only able to rethrow the exception from the return object's `resume()` function. But I'm not able to rethrow an exception that might happen BEFORE the resume function was first called, e.g. from the beginning of the coroutine until its first suspension point. This means I can't do any meaningful work without leaving the user wondering if that actually caused an exception, as the exception would have to be retrieved manually until this point.

The only solution I can think of is to always suspend at the beginning and have the coroutine not take any arguments, so use the coroutine function just for initialization and actually start it using the first `resume()` invocation. I think that is really awkward design, am I missing something?

Comment: "*have the coroutine not take any arguments*" Um, what? Exceptions thrown by the initialization of function parameters by their arguments *will* be thrown at the cite of the call. This is true of *all functions*.

Comment: "*I think that is really awkward design, am I missing something?*" Exceptions are ultimately the result of some process of a function. You *cannot* get the result of anything in a coroutine unless you ask for it. Exceptions are not special in this regard. If the coroutine didn't need to suspend at all and completed successfully, you'd still have to call `resume` or some other function to get the generated value.

Comment: "*This means I can't do any meaningful work without leaving the user wondering if that actually caused an exception, as the exception would have to be retrieved manually until this point.*" They're going to retrieve it anyway because they're *eventually* going to ask the coroutine to resume. If it can't resume due to having previously exited via an exception, then it can be thrown. The exception will not be *lost*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not necessarily. In my case my coroutine is a class member and it will construct an internal datastructure based on the given std::string_view. I would never have to return anything as the coroutine takes care of deploying the values to the datastructure, however, in case of failure the user would need to know right away. I figure I just have an exotic case.

Comment: "*I would never have to return anything as the coroutine takes care of deploying the values to the datastructure*" But the user needs to interact with this "internal datastructure" in some way. And therefore, it must talk to the coroutine future. The idea of "returning something" doesn't need to be literal. My point is that *any interaction* with the coroutine future is a point where you can emit that exception.

Comment: @NicolBolas I understand, but that would mean I would have to check for exception in every accessor of the class that holds the datastructure which is just not practical and also an unnecessary branching overhead. I will definitely opt for just passing nothing as an argument and then have the user feed the coroutine manually with a member function of the return type where I can rethrow eventual exceptions.

Comment: My ultimate question is this: why are you using a *coroutine* for this at all? This feels like you're trying to put a round peg in a square hole. If you expect your coroutine to be *done* by the end of the invocation function, it's not a "coroutine". And if it's not done, but the rest of the coroutine just uses the products of the first part, then that sounds like two function invocations, not a coroutine. It feels like you've violated some design principles somewhere, like maybe the Single Responsibility Principle (ie: if it's job is to build a data structure, then that's *all* it should do).

Comment: Put a different way, it really seems like you're trying to put object *construction* and object *manipulation* in the same function. And... you really shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the return_void function in your promise_type, something like this:

```
        void return_void() const
        {
            if (std::holds_alternative<std::exception_ptr>(val_))
            {
                throw std::get<std::exception_ptr>(val_);
            }
        }
```

In order to work, I recomend you using std::optional to store exception pointer:

```
std::variant<std::monostate, std::exception_ptr> val_;
```

You can see an example of exceptions with coroutines here
[Exceptions example with coroutines](https://github.com/JoseManuelVargas/cpp-coroutines/blob/main/samples/tasks_example.cpp)

Comment: Actually... that could work. Are you sure that the return function is called from the coroutine-caller's callstack though? Also, you probably meant to use `std::optional` instead of `std::variant`, right? Also, you could probably use `std::exception_ptr` directly as `std::exception_ptr` is allowed to store nullptr values (meaning "no exception")

Comment: Yes you are right. It could be std::optional, or even simpler with std::exception_ptr. std::variant is needed if we want to return also a value.

Answer (score 1):

Your coroutine does not suspend at the initial suspend point. It also does not suspend at the final suspend point. And it never `co_await`s or `co_yield`s. This means that it never actually suspends. So it completes before `main` ever sees it.

This is bad because, by the time `coroutine.resume()` gets called, [the coroutine state for the handle has been destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74424079/734069). That's what happens if you reach the final suspend point and don't suspend there. So using any function on the `coroutine_handle` (like calling `done()` or `resume()`) is UB.

If you want a coroutine to forward *anything* back to the owner of its future object (the return value of the coroutine), it *must* at least have a final suspend point.

Comment: Thanks, but what if it suspends? It still doesn't propagate the exception to the caller? If I change final suspend to always suspend and put the coroutine init into the try block, nothing is propagated. How do I do that? https://godbolt.org/z/sc9YaE8oM

Comment: @glades: Nothing propagates from a coroutine unless you explicitly cause it to propagate. The caller doesn't get the return value object from a future unless it *asks for the value* (one way or another). This is just as true of exceptions; you have to ask for something before you can get it.

Comment: That would mean that about the only way to propagate an exception in coroutine context is to store it using the unhandled_exception() hook and on the next invocation of say the resume function of the return object retrieve it from the underlying handle and rethrow it? This sounds really inconvenient and non-intuitive...

Comment: @glades: The word "coroutine" is a contraction of the term "cooperative routine". That is, you're talking about a concept that, by its nature, *requires* explicit cooperation to work. The receiver of the results of a coroutine has to cooperate with the coroutine to get them... by asking for them. That's just what a coroutine *is*. `co_await` is a way to syntactically transform a request for a coroutine's results into something that looks like it was not a coroutine call. The consequences of using it is that *your* routine also becomes a coroutine, cooperating with the other routine.

Comment: I understand that, but technically the coroutine still always executes in caller's context. It is not something like a thread that "executes on it's own", a coroutine just redirects instruction flow. Which makes me wonder why the execution is not just thrown accross to the caller thread for it to handle, bc if it's not the caller who handles it who will it be? Also, am I right in assuming that if a coroutine might throw, you would have to poke into the promise type and check for exceptions before every resumption of the coroutine?

Comment: @glades: "*technically the coroutine still always executes in caller's context*" Does it? The immediate caller can pass the return value to whomever it wants, and they can use that value to interact with the coroutine however they want.

Comment: How do you mean that? "The immediate caller can pass the return value to whomever it wants"

Comment: @glades: When you call a function that happens to be a coroutine, you get a return value back just like any other function. But for a coroutine function, that return value is how you interact with the coroutine (wait for a value, etc). The object represents the coroutine (or more accurately, any future value(s) it may give you). But that object is... *an object*, no different from any other. You can give that object to whomever you like, and that code will be able to interact with the coroutine. Just like you can pass a `std::future` around.

Comment: True but you still always either have 1 caller or you have a data race. In any case, my problem with coroutine boils down to the fact that there's no way to rethrow the exception through one of those "interaction" functions until it arrives at the first suspension point. The exception is just stored in a handle and execution flow resumes in caller context after the creation of the coroutine.

Comment: This means user code would have to rethrow the coroutine which is awkward. Essentially I will always have to initial_suspend and then trigger the start of the coroutine seperately with a call to return_type.resume() where I'm in a context to rethrow the excpeption from library code. That design makes me sad.

Comment: @glades: "*my problem with coroutine boils down to the fact that there's no way to rethrow the exception through one of those "interaction" functions until it arrives at the first suspension point.*"  The way a coroutine communicates with whomever is interacting with the return value is *at suspension points*; the first suspension point is not special. "*This means user code would have to rethrow the coroutine which is awkward.*" You can have a function in the return value rethrow the exception. That is, whatever `resume`-equivalent it has can also check for an exception and throw it.

Comment: Exactly, however I must force users to resume this coroutine from the first suspension point then which is the initial suspension point. So it can't do work beforehand as if that would throw an exception the exception would go unhandled. This is what I call awkward design.

Comment: @glades: What are you talking about? Some code creates the coroutine. That coroutine will suspend at some point. At that point, it either is simply suspended, suspends with a value (finished), or suspends with an exception (terminated). The controlling code is going to ask which state the coroutine is in because that's *how you communicate with it*. If it is suspended with an exception, that's when the exception is emitted. You have to talk to the coroutine, and that means calling a function on it. That function can emit an exception if that's how you want to handle the third state.

Comment: @glades: My point is that your example is one where code *never talks to the coroutine*. That is not how you use coroutines. So provide an example where the code can actually extract a value or check for the completion of the coroutine, and I will point to the exact line where the exception can be emitted.

Comment: I have updated my question, check the code. I think we mean the same thing, I just think it's unelegant and awkward design at best :X

Comment: @glades: Your edit didn't change anything meaningful. The answer is still the same; if you want the results of a coroutine, you must ask for them.